# If the string of L consists of 0's only prove that L* is regular

Tags: regular-language, automata

A question 4.2.10 from Introduction to Automata Theory by Hopcroft and Ullman. The original language L can also be non-regular.

Let's say we got a function of 0^(2^n+5), n>=0, how would you prove that (0^(2^n+5))* is regular? And also for the more general case, when f(0) can be any function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that L contains two strings 0^n and 0^m and that n and m share no common factors: they are relatively prime. Then, by concatenating some number of instances of 0^n with some number of instances of 0^m, any string of length (n - 1)(m - 1) can be formed. Since L* must therefore exclude only a finite number of words, the complement (L*)' must be finite, hence regular; because regular languages are closed under complement, L* must be regular too.

Where did (n - 1)(m - 1) come from? Well, it's a special case (n = 2) of the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) for which we have a closed-form solution. You should be able to research this and find some proofs.

What about the case where all strings in L have lengths divisible by some GCD, say g? Well, the proof of regularity is quite similar; consider a modified alphabet where 0 is replaced by the symbol (0^g) and then prove the analogous language over this alphabet is regular as above. In other words, you can show that L* contains only strings divisible by g and all strings divisible by g of length at least (n/g - 1)(m/g - 1) where n and m have GCD g. The language is regular because it excludes only finitely many words whose lengths are divisible by g.